# How to count unique combinations of Co-ordinates to find most customers in grid section

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a customer table with their closest delivery hub on a grid based system and need to calculate what is the most populated area using a query.

This is the current query I have that lists all of the Co-ordinates per Customer.

`SELECT Customers.HubID, TO_CHAR(Hubs.HubCoordX, 'FM999999999999') as "X Co-ordinate", TO_CHAR(Hubs.HubCoordX, 'FM999999999999') AS "Y Co-ordinate" FROM Customers INNER JOIN Hubs ON Customers.HubID = Hubs.DestinationID ORDER BY Hubs.HubCoordX, Hubs.HubCoordY`

This query creates the following result.

| HubID | X Co-ord | Y Co-ord |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | -3 | 1 |
| 11 | -2 | 18 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 7 | 3 |

But I need a result like this

| X Co-ordinate | Y Co-ordinate | Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -3 | 1 | 1 |
| -2 | 18 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 6 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 | 1 |

Thanks in advance

I have attempted use Count Unique however it resulted in only counting individual Co-ordinates once.

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT  TO_CHAR(Hubs.HubCoordX, 'FM999999999999') as "X Co-ordinate",
TO_CHAR(Hubs.HubCoordX, 'FM999999999999') AS "Y Co-ordinate", Count(HubID) as "Population"
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Hubs ON Customers.HubID = Hubs.DestinationID
Group BY Hubs.HubCoordX, Hubs.HubCoordY